# Telerik Reporting Graph

Tags: charts, telerik, reporting, telerik-reporting, telerik-charting

I'm trying to evaluate 2 reporting tools, SQL reporting and Telerik reporting, One of the thing my report should create are some charts. Here comes my problem. I would like to get a line chart that looks like this one created on my RDLC that is how I need it.

[image]

With Telerik I almost got the same graph but I still have some problems.

1. I can't eliminate the margins on the X axis (blue squares)
2. I can't find how to manually set the X axis interval (green square), searching on forums somebody sais that changing the scale property to **DateTime Scale** (It crashes my designer)
3. It is possible to move the axis with the ticks at the bottom of the chart (purple square) like it is on the rdlc chart?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end I got an answer on the telerik forum how to set the properties I was missing, if somebody is facing a similar problem the solution can be found here
[Chart Xaxis Margin and label interval](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/reporting/telerik-reporting/chart-xaxis-margin-and-label-interval.aspx) 

The problem in the purple square is solved by selecting the Y axis, from the scale property select CrossAxisPosition, add an element to the collection and set the position atminimum.